# Finding ObjectClassID of feature class in file geodatabase?

Tags: arcmap, file-geodatabase

Where do I find the ObjectClassID of a feature class in an ESRI GDB?

I am asking as I am writing a script with arcpy to delete a topology rule and need to know the ObjectClassID of the associated feature classes. I feel like this should be simple but I have found no online documentation from google.

Comment: is there a way to extrac or find all Class ID by a dataset?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/110116)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/110116)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the [Describe](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/dataset-properties.htm) function:

```
arcpy.Describe("<layer name>").DSID
```

The manual way

1. In the Catalog window of ArcMap, browse to the feature class.
2. Right-click the feature class, then choose Properties.
3. In the Feature Class Properties dialog box, click the General tab.
4. Click the button with the ellipsis, which is next to the Name text box.

The Object Class ID dialog box indicates the feature class ID.

Comment: awesome! thanks! the search for online documentation of this was futile for me. it seems like a simple thing that is in a goofy place haha.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to check the SDE.GDB_ITEMS table.  Look in the PhysicalName column for your table name, noting it may contain the schema owner or not, then the ObjectID of that row is your ObjectClassID.